# Problema con Java y NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jframe

Tengo un MacBook Pro. El caso que me he instalado NetBeans ultima versión y JDK de Java, en fín he instalado las herramientas necesarias.

El problema es que, cuando compilo, nunca me abre el terminal o el proyecto... si hago un print "hola" lo muestra abajo, y quiero que abra la consola (terminal)

En caso de poner un JFrame, más de lo mismo, no me abre el archivo Java.

Comment: Que te muestra el log??

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de código con el que te pase?

Comment: ¿En la parte inferior de Netbeans no ves las pestañas `Output`, `Terminal`, `Search Results`?  ¿Si seleccionas en el menú de arriba: `Window/IDE Tools/Terminal` no ves la ventana de Terminal? Por cierto, ¿acaso tu programa tiene que mostrar algo en la `Terminal` o se trata de un programa con una interfaz gráfica? Cierra todos los programas que tengas en  `Output` (pulsando en la `x` encerrada en un círculo gris que hay a la derecha de cada uno) e intenta de nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De hecho la pestaña que se muestra en la parte inferior es la consola de salida de tus desarrollos, como tal, se podría decir que es como tu CMD,Terminal o lo que uses, quizás podrías probar ubicar el path de tu proyecto y desde ahi ejecutar el jar/war/ear generado y listo.

La otra opción sería configurar tu Maven o Ant, dependiento lo que utilices para realizar tareas post-compilación, por ejemplo que se lanze Terminal con "X" comando.